# How to search a JSON file's key case insensititvely

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON object like below,

```
"Data Center": {
        "TMSLevel2": {
            "Comp-NX2/4/5/6K": "NX2/4/5/6K",
            "Comp-NX3K": "NX3K",
            "Comp-NX7K": "NX7K",
            "Comp-NX9K": "NX9K",
            "Comp-ACI": "ACI"
         }
}
```

I named the file as `map.js` and import it by `var map =  require ('./map.js')` from Node JS.
I am accessing it like `console.log(map["Data center"]["TMSLevel2"][name])`. Now the name be `"Comp-NX3K"` or `"Comp-NX3k"` or `"Comp-nx3K"`.

When it is `"Comp-NX3K"` it prints the corresponding value. But, if it is `"Comp-nx3K"` it prints `"undefined"` as there is no matching value.
How to fix it ??

Comment: do you mean to say the json key will be changing it;s key or while searching you will change it's case

Comment: there's nothing to `fix` - the code works as it should, you can't "make" javascript ignore case for object keys. You could make all the keys all lower case, then select using `name.toLowerCase()`

Comment: You can have a look at my answer below which used `Object.defineProperty` to mix and use as same as above `map["Data Center"]["TMSLevel2"]["comp-nx3k"]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could create a function to do a regex check like so:

```
function findValueOfProperty(obj, propertyName){
    let reg = new RegExp(propertyName, "i"); // "i" to make it case insensitive
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((result, key) => {
        if( reg.test(key) ) result.push(obj[key]);
        return result;
    }, []);
}
```

Example Usage

```
let result = findValueOfProperty(map["Data center"]["TMSLevel2"], name)
console.log(result);
```

You can bring it one step further my making it a prototype function

```
Object.prototype.find = function(propertyName) {
    return findValueOfProperty.bind(this, this);
};
```

And call it like so

```
var result = map["Data center"]["TMSLevel2"].find(name);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a quick hack:

```
let map2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(map).toUpperCase());
console.log(map2["DATA CENTER"]["TMSLEVEL2"]["COMP-NX3K"]);
```

This loses the case of the values in the object, but it looks like they are all upper case, so maybe no problem?

Comment: This will work, but as I said it's a hack.  The other answer is more correct.

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript object attributes are case sensitive, which means that JSON keys are also case sensitive. However, assuming you don't have a gargantuan list, then you could use `Object.keys`, `Object.values`, and create a lower-cased index.

```
var searchedFor = ("NX3K").toLowerCase(); // make sure to have them match case
var data =  {
            "Comp-NX2/4/5/6K": "NX2/4/5/6K",
            "Comp-NX3K": "NX3K",
            "Comp-NX7K": "NX7K",
            "Comp-NX9K": "NX9K",
            "Comp-ACI": "ACI"
         };
var iKeys = Object.keys(data) // this is a list of all of the attributed above (Comp-…)
               .map( // this calls a function on every member of an Array
                  function(x){ // this function returns a lower cased version of whatever
                               // value it was given
                      return x.toLowerCase();});

// iKeys is now an array of lower-cased keys.
var myValue = Object.values(data)[
                      // wherever the searched for element shows up, 
                      // will correspond to that value.
                      iKeys.indexOf(searchedFor)];
```

I do have to warn you, the above will only match the *first instance* of the key. So if there are cases of `Comp-NX9K` and `Comp-nx9k` you'll only get one.

Comment: You could make it a function that checks if the exact case is not undefined first before lower casing the keys which might help if you have collisions in the data.

Answer (score 3):

You can `deep clone` the `map` object to another object with all the keys lower cased and access the object properties with lower case key from the deep cloned object.

Sample:

```js
var map = {"Data Center": {
        "TMSLevel2": {
            "Comp-NX2/4/5/6K": "NX2/4/5/6K",
            "Comp-NX3K": "NX3K",
            "Comp-NX7K": "NX7K",
            "Comp-NX9K": "NX9K",
            "Comp-ACI": "ACI"
         }
}};

function clone(obj) {
  var cloned = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
     cloned[key.toLowerCase()] = (typeof obj[key] === 'object' ? clone(obj[key]) : obj[key]);
  });
  
  return cloned;
}

var mapCloned = clone(map);

console.log(mapCloned["data center"]["tmslevel2"]["comp-nx3k"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another nice solution using `Object.defineProperty` and with help of this, you can clone a new object and access its properties with any one of `original key`, `lower cased key` and `upper cased key` as below. You can mix them as well.

```js
var map = {"Data Center": {
        "TMSLevel2": {
            "Comp-NX2/4/5/6K": "NX2/4/5/6K",
            "Comp-NX3K": "NX3K",
            "Comp-NX7K": "NX7K",
            "Comp-NX9K": "NX9K",
            "Comp-ACI": "ACI"
         }
}};

function defineProperty(obj, prop, val) {
  Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
     get: function() {
       return val;
    }
  });
}

function clone(obj) {
  var cloned = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    var val = obj[key];
    if(typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
       val = clone(obj[key]);
    }
    
    defineProperty(cloned, key, val);
    
    if(key !== key.toLowerCase()) {
      defineProperty(cloned, key.toLowerCase(), val);
    }
    
    if(key !== key.toUpperCase()) {
      defineProperty(cloned, key.toUpperCase(), val);
    }
  });
  
  return cloned;
}

var map = clone(map);

console.log(map["data center"]["tmslevel2"]["comp-nx3k"]);

// mixed
console.log(map["Data Center"]["tmslevel2"]["comp-nx3k"])

// mixed more
console.log(map["Data Center"]["TMSLevel2"]["comp-nx3k"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Normalize your json

```
var map =   [
                {"Comp-NX2/4/5/6K": "NX2/4/5/6K"},
                {"Comp-NX3K": "NX3K"},
                {"Comp-NX7K": "NX7K"},
                {"Comp-NX9K": "NX9K"},
                {"Comp-ACI": "ACI"},
                {"Comp-NX3k": "NX3k"},
                {"Comp-nx3K": "nx3K"},
];

var normalizeMap = [];


for (var i=0;i<map.length;++i) {
  for (var key in map[i]) {
    //console.log(' name=' + key + ' value=' + map[i][key]);

    if (key == "Comp-NX3K" ||  key == "Comp-NX3k" || key == "Comp-nx3K") {
      var key_ = "Comp-NX3K";  
      var value =  map[i][key];        
    }
    else {
      var key_ = key;
      var value =  map[i][key];
    }
    var item = {};
    item[key_]=value;
  }


  console.log(item);
  normalizeMap.push(item);


}

console.log(normalizeMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my JSON file like following...

```
var data =  {
            "Comp-NX2/4/5/6K": "NX2/4/5/6K",
            "Comp-NX3K": "NX3K",
            "Comp-NX7K": "NX7K",
            "Comp-NX9K": "NX9K",

            "Comp-NX2/4/5/6k": "NX2/4/5/6K",
            "Comp-NX3k": "NX3K",
            "Comp-NX7k": "NX7K",
            "Comp-NX9k": "NX9K",
            "Comp-ACI": "ACI"
         }
```

In this way, it works for a very small number of keys/combinations. But `Object.keys` is a better Solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. It could be helpful.

```
var res= name.split("-")[0]+"-"+ name.split("-")[1].toUpperCase();
console.log(map["Data Center"]["TMSLevel2"][res]);
```